# i have column entry_date, i have to exclude data daily for last 3 year. Ex-between 2015-10-11 to current date, and so on

Tags: sql

```
entry_date

2014-09-05 00:00:00.0
2
2014-01-16 00:00:00.0
3
2014-06-06 00:00:00.0
4
2014-06-02 00:00:00.0
5
2014-05-13 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: Please Column your sample data and simplify it. Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

> you can use
>   1)SELECT * from Yourtablename WHERE entry_date  BETWEEN @fromdate AND @ToDate
>
> 2)SELECT * from Yourtablename WHERE entry_date>=@fromdate AND entry_date<=@ToDate

in @fromdate AND @todate you can specify your parameter value and 
in @fromdate start of the Day to @todate use  end of the day time 23 hours,59 minute ,59 seconds

Comment: Thanks but it will not work, i have to exclude data daily for last 3 year.
Ex - between 2015-10-11 to current date, 2015-10-12 to next date and so on.
How can i do that, tomorrow also same query should work because date will change tomorrow also.

Comment: and @toDate paramteter you can sprecify datetime.Now that will return current time so its work tommorow also

Comment: No bro, it's not working, the thing is that I can not specify datetime, I don't want to make it hardcoded, it should exclude 2015-10-11 to 2018-10-12 entire 3 year and then give me all old result before 2015-10-11

Comment: select * from dt_table where entry_date <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
AnalysisException: `databaseName`.curdate() unknown

Comment: above query is fine but I need some changes here, getting exception

Comment: What databases you are using ?

Comment: I am querying in Cloudera-Hue.

Comment: may be the curdate function have problem you can try now() instead of Curdate() and queries like   
select * from dt_table where entry_date <= DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 3 YEAR)